# How do I center a div and make it expand around the divs inside of it?

Tags: css, html

I have a page that I want centered, with a background and a border around the entire content.

I made a div and set it with the background color and the border settings I want.

Problem is that it has divs inside it that float and the background does not stretch around the floating divs. The only way I was able to get it to work was by setting position:absolute. Then the border did expand around the floating divs but I was unable to center them using regular html/css.

I found a javascript hack to make it center but it only centers after the page loads and it looks bad.

I am sure there is a way to have the container expand and still have it centered, I just can't figure it out.

here is a sample html page that shares my problems

```
<div style="background-color: Red; width: 980px; position: absolute;" id="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="width: 400px; background-color: Black; float: left;">
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; background-color: Blue; float: left;">
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Javascript that makes it work (uses Jquery)

```
$(function() {
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $("#container").css('left', winW / 2 - $("#container").width() / 2);
    });
```

There has got to be a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `auto` as left and right `margin` to center the element.

Put an element after the floating elements and use `clear` to put it below them. As it's not floating, it will affect the size of the outer div.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; background-color: Red; width: 980px;" id="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="width: 400px; background-color: Black; float: left;">
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 400px; background-color: Blue; float: left;">
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured there was a way, But I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

this is a tricky one, but I use the following code in stylesheets;

```
<style>div.sentor {text-align: center; height: 100%;} div.child{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 95%; height: 100%;}</style>
```

then in the body;

```
<div class="sentor">
<div class="child">
    <div id="mycontent">
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question well enough, but I think you're looking for something similar to this. Here's our simple layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="center">
            <!-- your content -->
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

To get the contents of div#center to move to the center of the page, we need the following CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

div#center {
    text-align: left;
    width: 600px;    // Or some other arbitrary width
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center everything within body. However, the text-align: center; property will also be applied to the children of body, so we cancel that out with the second style rule. Alternatively, in place of div#center, you could use the following style rule:

```
body * {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This uses a bug in Internet Explorer. It doesn't work in any other browser, as they follow the standard and don't apply text-align to block elements.

Comment: Yeah I left out the margin: 0 auto; part. I had forgotten about that. I've even incorporated it into numerous works of my own!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; background-color: Red; width: 980px; id="container">
```

The margin: 0 auto; will center the red div.

The overflow: hidden; will make the red div stretch to contain the two floating divs.